# Microsoft Excel Conditional String Output Formula

Tags: excel

### I'm trying to create a formula that takes in data formatted thusly:

Ex.

A1 Excel Data --> (**Useless Data - 'example'**)

1. Then, Grab the data after the 'hyphen' -> MID(A1,FIND("-",A1)+1,1)
2. Finally, look at the first letter of the selected data and sort it into four                 Categories -> IF(MID(A1,FIND("-",A1)+1,1)="e""E","Example"

#### Notes:

- Needs to search for both upper and lower-case lettering.
- If none of the statements are 'true' it should default to category 'other'
- Ideally a cool way to remove formatting such as '(', ' ', ', ' would be cool.

#### Function so Far:

```
=IF(MID(A1,FIND("-",A1)+1,1)="a""A","Amex",IF(MID(A1,FIND("-",A1)+1,1)="C""c","Citi Bank",IF(MID(A1,FIND("-",A1)+1,1)="W""w","Wells Fargo", "Other")))
```

Comment: What do you mean by `sort`?  It seems from your formula that what you want to do is return one of four strings?  And where is this formatting you want to remove?  That does not follow from your example, or your formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function will search for both upper and lower case, and will default to other.

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("a",MID(A1,FIND("-",A1)+1,1))),"Amex",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("c",MID(A1,FIND("-",A1)+1,1))),"Citi Bank",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("w",MID(A1,FIND("-",A1)+1,1))),"Wells Fargo", "Other")))
```

However, please strongly consider putting a list together that you can reference using an `INDEX` and `MATCH`.  Consider the following in columns `D` and `E`:

```
    D     E
    -------
    a   Amex
    c   Citi Bank
    w   Wells Fargo
```

Then just use this formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(E:E,MATCH(LOWER(MID(A1,FIND("-",A1)+1,1)),D:D,0)),"Other")
```

If you do need to remove formatting you can look into the `SUBSTITUTE` formula

Comment: Thank you! I'll have to look into Index and Matches more.